# How to hide the header of `createBottomTabNavigator` who is not allowing the headers of all classes implemented using `navigationOptions`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

All classes of my `React Native` code have their own header implemented using `navigationOptions` and I've created the `bottomTabNavigator` that has its own header overwriting the existing header and their functionality. How to hide the `bottomTabNavigator` header while own headers of classes work properly and accordingly?

I've used `header: null` and `navigationOptions: { header: null, }` in the stack of `bottomTabNavigator` and also `header: { visible: false, }` but it didn't work, as header is still visible.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Input, Icon, SearchBar, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

import Notification from './notification.js';
import Nearby from './nearby.js';
import Add from './add.js';

class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { search: '' };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Contacts',
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        style={{marginRight: 10,}}
        onPress={() => alert('Map is shown!')}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#3090C7', fontSize: 16 }}>View on Map</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerTitleStyle: { width: '110%', textAlign: 'center', },
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E4E4E2' }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3' }}>
        <SearchBar
          autoCorrect={false}
          placeholder='Search From Contacts'
          platform = 'ios'
          inputStyle = {styles.txt}
          onChangeText = {search => this.setState ({search})}
          value={this.state.search}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3' }}>
          <Text> Successfully Logged-In </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MainScreen, header: { visible: false, } },
  Notification: { screen: Notification, header: null, },
  Nearby: { screen: Nearby, header: null, },
  Add: { screen: Add, header: null, },
});

const Home = createAppContainer(HomeStack);
export default Home;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  txt: {
    color: '#3090C7',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },

  btn: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
})
```

I expect that header of `bottomTabNavigator` should be hidden and headers of each class should be visible.

Comment: How do you render a header on createBottomTabNavigator? As far as i know, there's no way to do it expect nesting it inside a stackNavigator or using stackNavigators as childs.

Comment: I've tried the other ways also, I used `createBottomTabNavigator` in the `createStackNavigator` and used `headerMode: 'screen'` in stackNavigator, but it shows both headers. In simple words, is there any way to hide the header of `createBottomTabNavigator`? if there is any way, I can manage my whole work through other ways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

screenOptions={{
headerShown: false,
title: '',
}}

[image]